# Large file uploading to a libevent-based HTTP server

Tags: c, http, networking, zeromq, libevent

I'm trying to write a HTTP  to ZeroMQ proxy  with libevent (2.0.4) which should be able to handle very large (up to 4GB) file upload.
The problem is I don't know how large post requests (larger than memory) are handled by libevent so if you have hints on how to implement large file uploading, please led me on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you read the libevent source code? it's very readable.

If you're using it's HTTP code, i think it uses the 'bufferedevent' (or is it evented buffers?) feature.  You can simply set callbacks when the input buffer reaches the highwater mark.

Comment: But can I still use the evhttp interface if I decide to use buffered events directly ? And will libevent correctly parse the multipart/form-data request ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will find some info in http://mongrel2.org/home since this is HTTP server and proxy that uses ZeroMQ for processing (backend handlers).